# last loggedin users in linux showing 8 characters only

Tags: linux

I am using last command in linux to fetch last loggedin user.
But last command shows only 8 characters in the username field. In the below image, username **administrator** is trimmed to **administ**.

Is there any other way to get the full name of last logged-in user ?

I tried lastlog too.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

`last -w` should do the trick for you.  I don't have any long usernames to test this with but the man page suggests it should work.

You can also use `last -a` to list hostnames as the last field and not truncate them or `last -i` to display them as IP addresses instead of hostnames.

These are local users to your system so you could grep them out of your `/etc/passwd` file if the above options don't work.  You should only run into problems doing that if you have two users that share the same first 8 characters.

Failing all of that, you could try `strings /var/log/wtmp`.  This data will be somewhat more difficult to interpret but it should contain the full usernames and hostnames.

Comment: @prasanna time to mark this the correct answers.

Comment: Note that -w doesn't seem to be supported on redhat

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

## show all available login since last restart:

last -Fw | grep -E 'Oct ([ 1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30)' | grep $(date +"%Y")

Comment: Aren't you going to explain why we can't live without those greps, and how it helps to work around the 8 character username limitation?

Answer (score -2):

`last` reads from utmp, and there the username field is limited to 8 characters. So it's better to have username somewhat unique within the first characters.

Comment: This is incorrect; while `utmp` stores only 8 characters, `last` actually reads from `wtmp` which can store full domain and user name.  `last -w` is the answer.